# How can I enable virtualization on a Sony VAIO with Win 7?

Tags: virtualization, bios

I'm trying to give my guest virtual machine more than one processor to use, so that it doesn't lag terribly. I finally discovered that I need to enable virtualization in the BIOS, but the BIOS only has two options: run Windows 7, or test Windows 7. How do I enable virtualization? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont see any option for virtualization in your BIOS, then most likely it doesnt support it.

Comment: I checked Securable and it said it does. Wikipedia also says it does. Could it have anything to do with my host OS being 64-bit (I think my Ubuntu guest is 32-bit)? Could I be in the wrong BIOS?

Comment: Nevermind. I was never in BIOS. I'm stupid.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside you might find it helpful in the future to use a tool such as [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to validate that the processor in question supports Virtualization. If it does the VT-x instruction on Intel Processors or AMD-V on AMD processors will show under the Instructions field. This in my experience will show up regardless if it has been enabled in the BIOS or not, so it will not tell you if it is enabled currently.

[image: VT-x is supported on this processor].

Answer (score 0):

Sony has disabled support for virtualization technology on their laptops.

Comment: Aside from personal experience, do you have a source for this?